# Non-numeric argument to binary operator error in Shiny

Tags: r, twitter, rstudio, shiny

I am running Rstudio IDE on my virtual machine. I am developing a twitter sentiment analysis app using Shiny. I am using the code placed at [Github](https://github.com/dipanjanS/MyShinyApps/blob/master/twitter-analysis/server.r).

I have changed the code of the function TwitterOAuth(). This is the code for server.R :

```
library(twitteR)
library(stringr)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(tm)
library(RJSONIO)
library(wordcloud)
library(gridExtra)
library(plyr)
library(shiny)
library(base64enc)
library(devtools)

#source("twitter_credentials.txt")

TwitterOAuth<-function(){
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"

consumerKey <- "Ls2EIqOFtJqRDsWbHpVusbPNr"
consumerSecret <- "Pzku2xDSQsSgHR1sFMV7uGivhZ7O6YoxJ1DTVzKVuNZimoI0Ha"

twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret = consumerSecret,
                         requestURL = reqURL,
                         accessURL = accessURL,
                         authURL = authURL)

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem",     package =  "RCurl")))
twitCred$handshake()
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
}

# Function to create a data frame from tweets
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  # Function to clean tweets, Stanton 2013
  CleanTweets<-function(tweets)
  {
    # Remove redundant spaces
    tweets <- str_replace_all(tweets," "," ")
    # Get rid of URLs
    tweets <- str_replace_all(tweets, "http://t.co/[a-z,A-Z,0-9]*{8}","")
    # Take out retweet header, there is only one
    tweets <- str_replace(tweets,"RT @[a-z,A-Z]*: ","")
    # Get rid of hashtags
    tweets <- str_replace_all(tweets,"#[a-z,A-Z]*","")
    # Get rid of references to other screennames
    tweets <- str_replace_all(tweets,"@[a-z,A-Z]*","")
    return(tweets)

  }

  #Search tweets and create a data frame
  TweetFrame<-function(searchTerm, maxTweets)
  {
    twtList<-searchTwitter(searchTerm,n=maxTweets,cainfo="cacert.pem",lang="en")
    twtList1<- do.call("rbind",lapply(twtList,as.data.frame))
    twtList1$text<-iconv(twtList1$text, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII') #WILL THIS SOLVE THE UTF ENCODING PROBLEM: http://lists.hexdump.org/pipermail/twitter-users-hexdump.org/2013-May/000335.html
    return(twtList1)

  }

  # function to calculate number of tweets (input is text column, if the entire data frame was submitted,
  #could've used nrow(), as done at a different place below)

  numoftweets<-function(entity1,entity2,entity1entry,entity2entry){
    ent1numtweets<-nrow(entity1)
    ent2numtweets<-nrow(entity2)
    notweets<-c(ent1numtweets,ent2numtweets)
    names(notweets)<-c(entity1entry,entity2entry)
    notweets
  }


  # function for word cloud

  wordcloudentity<-function(entitycleantext)
  {
    tweetCorpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(CleanTweets(entitycleantext)))
    tweetTDM<-TermDocumentMatrix(tweetCorpus,control=list(removePunctuation=TRUE,
                                                      stopwords=c(stopwords('english')),
                                                      removeNumbers=TRUE,tolower=TRUE))
    tdMatrix <- as.matrix(tweetTDM) # creating a data matrix
    sortedMatrix<-sort(rowSums(tdMatrix),decreasing=TRUE) # calculate row sum of each term and sort in descending order (high freq to low)
    cloudFrame<-data.frame(word=names(sortedMatrix),freq=sortedMatrix)#extracting names from named list in prev command and binding together into a dataframe with frequencies - called cloudFrame, names in separate columns

    wcloudentity<-wordcloud(cloudFrame$word,cloudFrame$freq,max.words=100, colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"),scale=c(8,1), random.order=TRUE)
    print(wcloudentity)
  }

  # Scoring sentiment expressed - Breen's algorithm
  #Jeffrey Breen: http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/twitter-text-mining-r-slides/
  #via Gaston Sanchez's twitter mining project: https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/sentiment/analysis

  score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words)
  {


    scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {

      # clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub():
      sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)
      sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)
      sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
      # and convert to lower case:
      sentence = tolower(sentence)

      # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package
      word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
      # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
      words = unlist(word.list)

      # compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms
      pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)
      neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)

      # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
      # we just want a TRUE/FALSE:
      pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)
      neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

      # and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():
      score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)

      return(score)
    }, pos.words, neg.words)

    scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences, size=seq(length(scores)))
    return(scores.df)
  }

  #calling the above sentiment scoring function, the text of tweets serve as inputs

  sentimentalanalysis<-function(entity1text,entity2text,entity1entry,entity2entry){

    positivewords=readLines("positive_words.txt")
    negativewords=readLines("negative_words.txt")
    entity1score = score.sentiment(CleanTweets(entity1text),positivewords,negativewords)
    entity2score = score.sentiment(CleanTweets(entity2text),positivewords,negativewords)

    entity1score$entity = entity1entry
    entity2score$entity = entity2entry
    entityscores<-rbind(entity1score,entity2score)

  }

  # Time for execution

  # Reading in values for the two entities
  entity1<-reactive({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                  detail = 'This may take a while...',
                  value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    entity1<-TweetFrame(input$entity1, input$maxTweets)}
  )
  entity2<-reactive({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                  detail = 'This may take a while...',
                  value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    entity2<-TweetFrame(input$entity2, input$maxTweets)}
  )


  #Creating sentiment scores
  entityscores<-reactive({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                  detail = 'This may take a while...',
                  value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    entityscores<-sentimentalanalysis(entity1()$text,entity2()$text,input$entity1,input$entity2)})
  output$notweets<-renderPrint({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                  detail = 'This may take a while...',
                  value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    numoftweets(entity1(),entity2(),input$entity1,input$entity2)})


  #tab 1: Not all chatter may be good. So a box plot to see the distribution of scores of sentiments

  output$sentiboxplot<-renderPlot({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                  detail = 'This may take a while...',
                  value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    cutoff <- data.frame(yintercept=0, cutoff=factor(0))
    sentiboxplot<-ggplot(entityscores(),aes(x=size,y=score))+
      facet_grid(entity ~ .)+
      geom_point(color = "black",size = 2, alpha = 1/2)+
      geom_smooth(method = "loess",se=FALSE,col='red',size=1.5, alpha = 0.7)+
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yintercept, linetype=cutoff), data=cutoff)+
      xlab('Tweet number')+
      ylab('Sentiment Score')+
      theme_bw()
    print(sentiboxplot)})

  # getting a feel for how sentiments were scored by scanning 4 tweets per entity and sentiment scores - data frame entity scores shown
  output$sentiheadtable<-renderTable({tab<-head(entityscores(),4)})
  output$sentitailtable<-renderTable({tab<-tail(entityscores(),4)})

  #tab 2 - Word Clouds to highlight terms used in tweets associated with the two entities
  output$entity1wc<-renderText({

    input$entity1})
  output$entity1wcplot<-renderPlot({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                  detail = 'This may take a while...',
                  value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    wordcloudentity(entity1()$text)})

  output$entity2wc<-renderText({input$entity2})
  output$entity2wcplot<-renderPlot({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                  detail = 'This may take a while...',
                  value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    wordcloudentity(entity2()$text)})


  #tab  3: Raw tweets of entity 1
  output$tableentity1 <- renderTable({tab<-entity1()[1]})

  #tab 4: Raw tweets of entity 2

  output$tableentity2<-renderTable({tab<-entity2()[1]})


})
```

This is the code for ui.R :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)

shinyUI(fluidPage(



  headerPanel("Twitter Analytics - Sentiment Analysis and more"),

  # Getting User Inputs

  sidebarPanel(

    wellPanel(
      textInput("entity1", "Handle 1: ","#thrilled"),
      textInput ("entity2","Handle 2: ","#frustrated"),
      HTML
      ("<div style='font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold'> Feel free to replace above text with your own twitter handle name 
          starting with '@' or hashtag starting with '#'</div>")
    )  ,
    wellPanel(
      sliderInput("maxTweets","Number of recent tweets to use for analysis:",min=10,max=300,value=30,step=1), # The max can, of course, be increased
  actionButton(inputId='actb',icon =icon("twitter"), label="Hit it!")
    )

  ),

  mainPanel(
    progressInit(),
    tabsetPanel(

      #Output from tab 4 ----So a box plot to see the distribution of scores of sentiments 
      tabPanel("Sentiment Analysis", plotOutput("sentiboxplot"), HTML
           ("<div> This plot shows the distribution of positive/negative sentiments about each entity. Note that tweets were cleaned before this analysis was performed. For each tweet, a net score of positive and negative sentiments are computed and this plot shows the distribution of scores.A higher sentiment score suggests more positive (or a less negative) discussion of that entity than the other.</div>"),
               tableOutput("sentiheadtable"),tableOutput("sentitailtable"),id="test"),

      #Output from tab 5 - Word clouds - with some html tags

      tabPanel("Word Clouds",h2(textOutput("entity1wc")),plotOutput("entity1wcplot"),h2(textOutput("entity2wc")),plotOutput("entity2wcplot")),

      #Output from tabs 6 and 7, the raw tweets
      tabPanel("Entity 1 Raw tweets",tableOutput("tableentity1")),
      tabPanel("Entity 2 Raw tweets",tableOutput("tableentity2"))
    )
  )

))
```

After running the code on Rstudio, i am getting the following error:

```
Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

This is the snapshot:

[image]

I have gone through many questions on SO having the error mentioned above, but all the cases are different. Please, provide me with the solution to resolve this particular error. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to read the code in your snapshots, and it's not clear to me that we can see the relevant parts in the snippet you've shown. Would you please post the full scripts, or at least the parts that are meant to produce the content you're trying to display on that tab?

Comment: I have edited the question. Now it has source code instead of snapshots.